# Take the full path waypoints of a railway

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

[image]I'm developing a Train Valley game, just like 2D. The construction of the railway is different. I have a grid and I can take a rail and put it somewhere in the grid and so the railway is built. The main problem I am facing is that I do not know how to create the way for the train to follow .... each sine has a point, this point I add in a Vector3 type list, but if I jump over a cell and put there sine , then go back to the skipped cell and put the rail there, then the list will no longer be sorted. 
I'm attaching code, but it's a lot. In general, if anyone has any idea how to build this path, the train will run correctly by all means.

```
void Start()
{
    foreach (TrainCell cell in Grid)
        cell.gameObject.AddComponent<TrainCellMouseEvent>().MouseEvent += OnCellClickEvent;
    MouseEventProccessor.Instance.captureMouseMouveEvents = true;
    StartCoroutine(SpawnStations());
}
private void OnCellClickEvent(TrainCell target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK)
    {
        if (canDestroy)
        {
            if ((int)target.CurrentChildIndex != 0)
            {
                target.CurrentChild.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().enabled = false;
                target.setCurrentChildIndex(0);
                Instantiate(BoomFX, target.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                target.used = false;
                WayPoints.Remove(target.transform.position);
                if (BuildDone != null)
                    BuildDone(price, false);
            }
            foreach (TrainCell cell in Grid)
            {
                if (!cell.underBuilding)
                {
                    if (cell.CurrentChildIndex == 0 && cell.used)
                        cell.used = false;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        if (rail.SelectedRail == null || target.used || outOfGridBounds)
            return;

        int railIndex = (int)rail.SelectedRail.GetComponent<ObjectSequence>().CurrentChildIndex;
        target.setCurrentChildIndex(railIndex + 1);
        target.CurrentChild.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().enabled = true;
        MouseEventProccessor.Instance.captureMouseMouveEvents = true;
        SpriteRenderer render = target.CurrentChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        render.color = Vector4.one;
        target.used = true;
        if (BuildDone != null)
            BuildDone(price, true);

        if (target.CurrentChild.transform.childCount == 0)
            WayPoints.Add(target.transform.position);
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < target.CurrentChild.transform.childCount; i++)
                WayPoints.Add(target.CurrentChild.transform.GetChild(i).transform.position);
        }
    }
    else if (type == MouseEventType.OVER)
    {
        if (mainLevel.isHammer)
        {
            if (target.CurrentChildIndex != 0)
                target.CurrentChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
            return;
        }

        if (rail.SelectedRail == null || target.used)
            return;

        foreach (TrainCell cell in Grid)
        {
            if (cell.CurrentChildIndex != 0)
            {
                if (cell != target)
                {
                    if (cell.CurrentChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != Color.white && !cell.used && !cell.underBuilding)
                    {
                        if (cell.GetComponentInChildren<ObjectSequenceNumberDisplay>() != null)
                            Destroy(GetComponentInChildren<ObjectSequenceNumberDisplay>().gameObject);
                        cell.setCurrentChildIndex(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int railIndex = (int)rail.SelectedRail.GetComponent<ObjectSequence>().CurrentChildIndex;
        target.setCurrentChildIndex(railIndex + 1);
        RenderColor(target);
    }
    else if (type == MouseEventType.EXIT)
    {
        if (target.CurrentChildIndex != 0)
            target.CurrentChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        if (shapePrice != null)
            Destroy(shapePrice.gameObject);
        if (target.used)
            return;
        target.setCurrentChildIndex(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I suppose based on your code I'll try to answer your question based on the following statements:

- You have a station where you generate the train
- You define a direction for the train to follow from the station (left, right, up, down) depending on the railway design

Having that statements I propose the following solution:

- Create a method that takes the station point as the origin and the starting direction from that point. Having that you start following the railway, first on that direction and after that you search in 4 directions for more rails, adding all of them to the Vector3 array. This way you will have the array sorted.

Example:

```
private void SortedRailway(Vector2 origin, Vector2? direction = null, Vector2? lastDirection = null){
   if(direction.HasValue){
      if(origin + direction is TrainCell){
         WayPoints.add(origin + direction);
         SortedRailway(origin + direction, null, direction);
      }
      //(else will be used if direction (just used for the initial one) is wrong, so error there)
   }else{
      if(origin + Vector2.up is TrainCell && Vector2.up != lastDirection){
         WayPoints.add(origin + Vector2.up);
         SortedRailway(origin + Vector2.up, null, Vector2.down); //lastDirection is always the opposite to the matching one
      }
      //... (Repeat for all 4 directions. If none fits, then we asume is the end of the railway)
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you!